# where to declare objects?

Tags: javascript, reference, garbage-collection, structure

I have a program that basically looks like this and the function func seems to have access to the objects forever even though the onload function itself terminates quickly. Is this valid or am I accessing pieces in memory that are pending to be garbage collected?

Should I change this

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var obj1;
    var obj2;
    var obj3;

    addEventListener("click"  , func, true);
    addEventListener("blur"   , func, true);
    addEventListener("keydown", func, true);

    function func(evt)
    {
        function1(obj1);
        function2(obj2);
        function3(obj3);
    }
}
```

into this ?

```
var obj1;
var obj2;
var obj3;

window.onload = function()
{
    addEventListener("click"  , func, true);
    addEventListener("blur"   , func, true);
    addEventListener("keydown", func, true);

    function func(evt)
    {
        function1(obj1);
        function2(obj2);
        function3(obj3);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the 3 `addEventListener` definitions?

Comment: What is relation between `obj1` and `addEventListener`? Are you doing something with `obj1`? Where is `removeEventListener`?

Comment: I've added some examples. I do not use removeEventListener.

Comment: You mention a function incommingEvents, but I don't see that anywhere in your examples.

Comment: It was renamed it to function func, I've updated it